# Required Validator for RadioButtonGroup in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have this Validator for a `TextBox`:

```
<div style="margin-top:10px" class="autenticacionTitulo">Nombre y Apellido:</div>
        <div style="margin-top:5px"><asp:TextBox ID="nombre" runat="server" MaxLength="100" ValidationGroup="Curriculum" CssClass="autenticacionTextBox"></asp:TextBox></div>
        <div class="textoError">
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Validator2" runat="server"
          ErrorMessage="Escribe tu nombre y apellido" ControlToValidate="nombre"
          Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Curriculum"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
```

So, if the user doesn't writes anything, it throws a texterror, that field needs to be filled.

Now, i need validator like this but for a RadioButtonList:

```
<div class="autenticacionTituloR">¿Usa Lentes?</div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList6" RepeatColumns = "2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table"  runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem ValidationGroup="Curriculum" style="margin-right:12px; margin-top:-10px" >Si</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem ValidationGroup="Curriculum" >No</asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList></div>
```

Should i just put same RequiredFieldValidator, or there is another function to accomplish this with RadioButtons as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RequiredFieldValidator to validate RadioButtonList.

**ValidationGroup must be at RadioButtonList (instead of each ListItem)**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList6" RepeatColumns="2"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" runat="server" 
    ValidationGroup="Curriculum">
    <asp:ListItem>Si</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
    ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList6" Text="Required" 
    ValidationGroup="Curriculum">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Btw when i click back to the page i already filled, radiobuttons keeps selected, with this same code, do you know a way to refresh it? i mean to be editable, or to step back?

Comment: Gonna open a new question for that, nevermind, thank you again!